# Why are my Global Variables not working?

Tags: javascript, function, scope

Im sure this is a silly/simple question, but it is really puzzling me.  I understand 'Global Scope', and how functions have access to Global Variables, and their inner variables.

For some reason, my 'test' function, cannot access the global variables. When my 'test' function 'alerts' global variables it returns 0.  But when I move those 'global' variables to 'local' variables it works.

Why are my global variables not working?

My question is specifically for the variables 'years' and 'months'

This alert's 0 (Global Scope) (In regards to the years variable):

```
//Varibles
var mortgageAmount = getById('mAmount');
var mortgageAmountOutput = logger('mAmount');
var calc = getById('calculateBtn');
var years = +document.getElementById('mPeriod').value;
var months = years*12;


//Functions
function test() {
  //Test to see if numbers are 'numbers'
  //Populate Page
  populateMortgage();
  populateIntRate();

  //Math

  alert("My Mortgage is for: " + years + " years, or for " + months + " months " );



}
```

When I move the variable declaration from the global scope, to local, it works just fine:

```
//Varibles
var mortgageAmount = getById('mAmount');
var mortgageAmountOutput = logger('mAmount');
var calc = getById('calculateBtn');

//Functions
function test() {
  //Test to see if numbers are 'numbers'
  //Populate Page
  populateMortgage();
  populateIntRate();

  //Math  
  var years = +document.getElementById('mPeriod').value;
  var months = years*12;

  alert("My Mortgage is for: " + years + " years, or for " + months + " months " );

}
```

Comment: I'd suggest that the DOM is not ready when you try to grab your values. Place your code that retrieves the DOM values in to a ready handler of some kind.

Comment: Forgive my noobish, what do you mean a ready handler?  Such as a .addEventListener?

Comment: `document.onload = function(){ /* ... Script here ... */ }`

Comment: When the page loads you are assuming that the values in `mPeriod` etc, are available for you. This is not the case. You need to wait until they are.

Comment: The problem is not variable visibility. If it were, `years` would alert as `undefined`. The issue is that the value of `document.getElementById('mPeriod').value;` changed while `populateXXX()` was running.